# NSURL doesn't like get variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting an error when I pass a string to an NSURL.

```
Entity: line 6: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
zzzzzzz.com/feeds/rss/zzzz/zzzz/get_feed.php?c=zzzz&s=zzzz&f
```

It doesn't stop the app or anything but I feel like it should be addressed.  Looks like it doesn't like the `&` symbol.  I tried replacing with `&amp;` but that doesn't do the trick.

```
NSString *blogAddress = @"http://zzzzzz.com/feeds/rss/zzzz/zzzz/get_feed.php?c=zzzz&s=zzzz&f=most_recent";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: blogAddress];
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: The & symbol should not be a problem.  Can you post your code for how you create the `NSURL`?

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding your URL string like this...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[blogAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to URLEncode your String.  I used a category to do it:

URLUtils.h:

```
@interface NSString (URLUtils)

- (NSString *) urlEncodeValue;

@end
```

URLUtils.m:

```
#import "URLUtils.h"


@implementation NSString (URLUtils)

- (NSString *) urlEncodeValue {
    return (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef) self,
                                                               NULL,
                                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
}

@end
```

Then after including `URLUtils.h` in your class, you can do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [blogAddress urlEncodeValue]];
```

That should do it.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but spits this out: 
http%3A%2F%2Fzzzzzz.com%2Ffeeds%2Frss%2Fzzzz%2Fzzzz%2Fget_feed.php%3Fc%3Dzzzz%26s%3Dzzzz%26f%3Dmost_recent

Comment: You should only pass your query string to URLEncode.  Sorry I was not clearer.